# Why does MultipleLocator add extra ticklabels to the list of ticklabels of an axis?

Tags: matplotlib, ticker

I noticed the following confusing behaviour in matplotlib when using 
`MultipleLocator`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)

y = x**3

fig = plt.figure() fig.canvas.draw()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x,y)

#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))

fig.show()

ticks = [t.get_text() for t in ax.get_xticklabels()]
```

When ticking is done automatically (commenting out the line `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))`), the text elements in the list `ticks` is going from '0' to '10' (in steps of 2).

```
In [194]: ticks 
Out[194]: [u'0', u'2', u'4', u'6', u'8', u'10']
```

However as soon as I switch on the use of MultipleLocator, two extra empty strings get added at the front and the end of the list.

```
In [197]: ticks
Out[197]: ['', u'0', u'2', u'4', u'6', u'8', u'10', '']
```

This is confusing.
Can anyone explain me where this behaviour comes from?

Comment: short answer: mpl internals.  Extra tick locations _may_ be generated by the locators which are pruned at draw time.

Comment: but what is confusing is that it is not documented. I found this out accidentally  because i wanted to modify the last tick label on the axis. But whenever I did something like ax.get_xticklabels()[-1] I never ended up being able to modify anything.